# Filtering data in Linq c#

Tags: linq

| Val | param | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | 1 |
| 4 | 100 | 1 |
| 5 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 200 | 0 |
| 5 | 200 | 0 |

i want linq filteration c# to filter like this

| Val | param | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 4 | 100 | 1 |

1)I want to eliminate rows with status zero '0'

2)I want to eliminate all rows containing same **val** column values if one is having status 0

Help will be appreciate.
thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you get stuck trying this, or, where *specifically* do you need help?

Comment: i got stuck in 2nd condition I am not able to achieve it

Comment: It would help to post this as a [mre]. If people want to help you have to give them some starting point.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
var data = new List<Item>()
{
new Item(1,100,1),
new Item(2, 100,    1),
new Item(3, 100,    1),
new Item(4, 100,    1),
new Item(5, 100,    1),
new Item(3, 200,    0),
new Item(5, 200,    0)
};

IEnumerable<Item> dataWithNonZeroSatus = data.Where(d=> d.Status !=0);
int[] itemsToSkip = data.Except(dataWithNonZeroSatus).Select(v=> v.Val).ToArray();

var result = dataWithNonZeroSatus.Where(item=> !itemsToSkip.Contains(item.Val));
result.Dump();
    
}

class Item{
public int Val{get;set;}
public int param{get;set;}
public int Status{get;set;}
public Item(int val, int par, int status)
{
    Val = val;
    param = par;
    Status =status;
}
}
```

Result:

[image]